# DefaultHttpClient.class (org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient )Source Not Found

Tags: java, android, rest, mobile, class-library

I am new to `Android`.
I am trying to connect to a `RESTful` web service that I created. But when the compiler hits "`HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();`" line of code I get a `ClassNotFound` (org.apache.http.impl.client.defaulthttpclient classnotfoundexception) exception and its shows :

```
![Source Not Found for DefaultHttpClient][1].
```

I have tried adding httpClient.jar to sdk/sources/android15 but no luck. I also tried building the path and pointing to the location where i saved the sources file.

Comment: clean your project once.

Comment: I did that but the compiler still comes here:     public Class<?> loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return loadClass(className, false);
    }